# VBA how to open two file and copy date between them

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a macro, I have a sample file with a button that I would like to use to run two files in the background. One wb = this is a template and wbMe pli with data that I would like to copy to wbMe. However, when I run the code, I get subcprite out of range. Where I have an error, such a sheet exists + there is data there in the cell

```
Sub COREP_ITS()

Dim strPath As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook


strPath = selectFile
If strPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook

MyFolder = "sample_folder"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\CMR - CJ_MINIMAL*.xlsx")
If MyFile <> "" Then
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
Else
Exit Sub
End If

''C_0700_002''
wbMe.Sheets("Tabela_COREP").Range("F14").Copy
wb.Sheets("C_0700_0002").Range("G14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub

Private Function selectFile()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsx"

If .Show = True Then selectFile = .SelectedItems(1)

End With
End Function
```

Comment: Subscript out of range means that the sheet does not exist in the workbook. Be very careful when typing sheet names. Leading or trailing whitespace is a common source for why the names fail to match.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the file I select with selectFile () doesn't even open for me. If I even delete the copy / past part, it only opens the wbME file for me, and when I choose a file from wb, it does not open it, unfortunately, I don't know why

Comment: You get a selected path in `strPath` but then you never use it?  It won't open itself.   Why ask the user to choose a file and then instead open a files using the result from Dir() ?

Comment: @Tim Wlliams I need to open two separate files.  One automatically, where there is template after via Dir () and by selectfile the data file that I want to paste into template.  However, the macro button is in a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't open the user-selected file.

You need to pass `strPath` to `Workbooks.Open`

```vb
strPath = selectFile
If strPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set wbMe = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
```